# Partition mount point keeps changing

Tags: mount

The system changes my partition mount name with a numeric suffix dynamically (Example: `Name` becomes `Name1`, `Name2`, and so on).

I appreciate all your suggestions to fix this problem in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Thanks

Comment: I do not want to rename the Label . when I mount the partition from nautilus,  it is getting mounted with different name. For example, if my partition name is 'X' it is getting mounted as 'X1' or 'X2'.

Comment: @DineshKalidassan I think I've had this problem. Specifically, the **mount point** is getting renamed every time you mount the position, right?

Comment: Exactly, the mount point is renamed. Did you fix the problem.

Comment: @DineshKalidassan Yes, I did, though I'm foggy on the details, even after finding the question I posted: [Secondary HDD mounting in /media/username under wrong folder name](https://askubuntu.com/q/542996/301745)

Comment: OK, I've read some things and I think I have an answer ready - just need to know the method you're using to mount the partition.

Comment: I mount via nautilus.

Comment: I always use pmount so it is automatic.  See  https://askubuntu.com/questions/88523/creating-a-mount-point-if-it-does-not-exist/941726#941726 - instructions for installing `pmount` so it is always the same mount point.

Comment: Voting to reopen since the linked question is totally different. This question is not asking "How do I change the partition label?" - it's asking "How do I stop the mount point from changing?" The only thing it has in common is that the mount point is named after the partition label.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to happen when three conditions are met:

1. You mount the partition using the GUI (Nautilus or otherwise)

   - In the backend, this seems to use `udisksctl mount`
2. There is no entry for the partition in the filesystem table (/etc/fstab)

   - If there were an entry, it would specify the mount point
3. There is already a directory at the default mount point

   - The default mount point is `/media/$username/$partition_label`, so in this case, probably `/media/dinesh/Name`
   - I'm not sure why this happens. Maybe if the machine is not properly shut down?
   - It could also be a file not a dir, but practically, that doesn't happen

So, there are three solutions:

#### 1. Delete the existing dir(s)

This is quick and dirty - more of a workaround than a solution.

With the drive unmounted, run this command:

```
sudo rmdir /media/$USER/Name*
```

Note that rmdir will only delete empty dirs, so if you accidentally run this while the drive is mounted, it shouldn't do any harm.

#### 2. Create an entry for the partition in /etc/fstab

From [nathwill's answer on a related question](https://askubuntu.com/a/6272/301745):

> For a long-term fix, you could add the drive to /etc/fstab with a designated mountpoint. I recommend using the UUID to identify the drive.
>
> Bonus tip: If you want the icon to be displayed when the drive is mounted, set the mountpoint somewhere within /media/. If you don't, set the mountpoint somewhere else, such as /mnt/.

If you prefer GUI, you can use Disks (`gnome-disks`) to set up an fstab entry:

1. From the Dash, type "Disks" then open it

   - Or from a terminal, run `gnome-disks`
2. Select the disk
3. Select the partition
4. Click the **gear icon** (for more actions)
5. Click **Edit Mount Options**
6. Disable **Automatic Mount Options**
7. Set **Identify as** to **UUID=(uuid)**
8. Set the **Mount point**

#### 3. Mount the partition using CLI

This uses `sudo mount`, which IMO is way more hassle than the other two options, so I won't even bother explaining it.

---

#### More details

When using `udisksctl mount`, if the default mount point already exists, it will append `1`. If the mount point with `1` already exists, it will iterate the number (`2`, `3`, etc). It seems like earlier versions of Ubuntu used `udisks --mount` in the backend, which would mount to `/media/$partition_label`, and append an underscore if the mount point already existed. For example, see [Why does the mount point keeps changing, and how can I prevent it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2126/301745)