# Why does Ubuntu change mount point?

Tags: automount

I have an SD card with two partitions labeled BOOT and DATA; BOOT is FAT32 and DATA is ext2.  When I insert it into the card reader, automount properly mounts DATA but morphs the name of BOOT into BOOT1.  Why does it do that and how can I make it mount to BOOT?  And by that I mean /media//BOOT.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I looked at the partitions with gparted and saw that the mount point was indeed /media/<user>/BOOT1.  I unmounted the partition from within gparted and removed/reinserted the card.  Now it says BOOT.  I'm glad a three-day weekend is coming. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing typically happens when there already exists a directory with the same name on the mounting location. It can be another BOOT partition mounted or it may happen that unmounting was unsuccessfull or not done at all. In that case the directory may stay there. When you try to mount it next time it will add number 1 as is original mounting point already taken.

It mounts it to the directory `/media/<username>/`. Check what you have in that directory by typing `ls /media/<username>/`, where you put your username instead of `<username>`. Or navigate to `/media/<username>` and see what you have there. Delete any directories which may be ledt there, but be careful if they are actualy mounted. In that case, you may delete the mounted partition content.

Comment: Thanks!  I think the root cause was a case of removing the card without ejecting it first.  I'll have to be careful about that going forward.

Comment: `be careful if they are actualy mounted. In that case, you may delete the mounted partition` see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975245/925128): *"`sudo rmdir /media/$USER/Name*`* 
*Note that `rmdir` will only delete empty dirs, so if you accidentally run this while the drive is mounted, it shouldn't do any harm."* Deleting without sudo that folder while drive is mounted cannot be done, for example in the file manager. With admin rights in Dolphin it cannot be removed while mounted.