# Name of the directory changed automatically

Tags: partitioning, mount, 20.04, disk, disk-management

ls /media/name/

DATA/  DATA1/ DATA2/ OS/    OS1/   OS2/

Please see the above output. Initially, the partition name was DATA but changed to DATA1, then DATA2, where DATA and DATA1 became accessible from the root only. Sometimes I can not mount this partition, and when I restart the machine and I see that the partition name has changed.

Why is that happening, and what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Looks like your USB device comes up, disappears and comes back again before the old mount point was removed (which explains the +1, +2 added to DATA). Is it a harddisk? In what way is it powered? Tried another USB(3!) port?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I recently found a solution. https://askubuntu.com/questions/974741/partition-mount-point-keeps-changing

Comment: I'm assuming you deleted the `/media/user/DATA[123]`. The question remains why this is happening. Plug your drive in and do `dmesg | tail -50` in a terminal and check for any irregularities. Are you ejecting or umounting the drive after each use?