# When I mount a certain partition under the DISKS app it adds a "1" to the mount point UUID?

Tags: uuid

I do not understand why when a certain hard drive partition is mounted using the DISKS utility app it adds a "1" to the UUID for the mount point location. When I do this on another partition of the same drive when it mounts the UUID remains identical with no addition of a "1."
This is causing issues using BACKUPS utility and looking for the folder that has the backup files.

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

I can go in terminal and look at /media/Ed directory and it will show two:

04e8bdce-0446-4973-96c5-7cd2afd52d5d

04e8bdce-0446-4973-96c5-7cd2afd52d5d1

46bb87f5-1727-491a-addb-abdfccf07588  [other partition that UUID does not change]

If I unmount it the directory listing /media/Ed shows:

04e8bdce-0446-4973-96c5-7cd2afd52d5d

46bb87f5-1727-491a-addb-abdfccf07588

I cannot delete it because it is mounted and when unmounted it does not show up in the
directory listing using Terminal Mode.
Should I delete the partition/reformat or what? Yeah, I'm confused....lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid adding numbers to USB disks partition label/UUID when mount point exists under /media/user](https://askubuntu.com/q/1478033)

Comment: No that link was not helpful. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Explain: you say ""if I unmount it in the directory listing", it shows, then next paragraph you say "when unmounted it does not show up in the directory". Confusing. When unmounted, it either shows up or does not show up. This will need some clarification. Anyway, why using Disks to mount the drive? It should automount.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid adding numbers to USB disks partition label/UUID when mount point exists under /media/user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478033/avoid-adding-numbers-to-usb-disks-partition-label-uuid-when-mount-point-exists-u)