# Writing udev rules - wildcards?

Tags: usb, udev, multiseat

Is it possible to use wildcard characters when writing udev rules? I have multiseat and i want to assign every device (keyboard, mouse etc) that gets connected to a certain USB hub - or even better, a specific port on the front of the PC - to seat1. It's kind of cumbersome to have to redo new rules each time i swap stuff around or don't remember in which USB slot each device was connected.

Using just simple udev rules, as generated by 'loginctl attach' command:

```
TAG=="seat", ENV{ID_FOR_SEAT}=="usb-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_5_3", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat1"
```

Comment: Maybe its a good idea, to add the code you have already to the question.

Comment: @Marco thanks, done. No idea how i didn't think of that =)

Comment: UDEV rules accept some [simple shell style pattern matching](https://linux.die.net/man/8/udev) ... So, something like `usb-pci-*` should work.

Comment: Also please see how pattern matching is used here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1478053/968501

Comment: @Raffa Thanks, i searched all manpages i could think of, including that one, except not for the phrase "pattern character" ...this is a clear case of poor documentation of udev.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use wildcard characters when writing udev rules?

Yes, it's possible according to [`man udev`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/udev.7.html):

> Most of the fields support shell glob pattern matching and alternate
> patterns. The following special characters are supported:
>
> ```
>    "*"
>        Matches zero or more characters.
>
>    "?"
>        Matches any single character.
>
>    "[]"
>        Matches any single character specified within the brackets. For example, the pattern
>        string "tty[SR]" would match either "ttyS" or "ttyR". Ranges are also supported via
>        the "-" character. For example, to match on the range of all digits, the pattern
>        "[0-9]" could be used. If the first character following the "[" is a "!", any
>        characters not enclosed are matched.
>
>    "|"
>        Separates alternative patterns. For example, the pattern string "abc|x*" would match
>        either "abc" or "x*".
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> I have multiseat and i want to assign every device (keyboard, mouse etc) that gets connected to a certain USB hub

You can assign a USB controller to a seat. Everything that gets plugged into is is automatically assigned to the same seat as the controller.

No wildcard required.